# Grails: Get user object (user field) in gsp

Tags: spring, security, grails

I wanna show a field of the logged in user in the nav bar of my website. What is the best approach to get the user object in a gsp file? With

```
 <sec:username/>
```

I just get the username.

My nav bar, defined in my layout, is shown on every gsp page I have. I don't wanna pass the user object from every controller action (springSecurityService.loadCurrentUser()) to every gsp file.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#securityTagLib) for the plugin. You will see it provides a tag library for accessing this information (among other things).

From the documentation:

> Displays the value of the specified UserDetails field
>   if logged in. For example, to show the username property:
>
> ```
> <sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username"/>
> ```

To display something if the user is logged in you can do the following:

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
Welcome Back!
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

Comment: But then I have to create a userdetails domain object? I would prefer a solution without another user domain object. I already use the spring security facebook plugin where a FacebookUser domain object is created.